# R apply() function format() over POSIXct

Tags: r, apply, posixct

I have a `data.frame` that contains two columns:

- `UTCTime` which is an event time in the UTC zone
- `TimeZone` which is the actual time zone where an event took place

Sample of my data:

```
UTCTime <- as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-12 17:23:14", "2018-04-12 17:17:14","2018-04-12 07:48:20", "2018-04-12 11:25:04", "2018-04-12 11:24:38"), tz = "UTC")
TimeZone <- c("Europe/Prague", "Europe/Dublin", "Europe/Prague", "Europe/Prague", "Europe/Prague")
df <- cbind.data.frame(UTCTime, TimeZone, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
              UTCTime      TimeZone
1 2018-04-12 17:23:14 Europe/Prague
2 2018-04-12 17:17:14 Europe/Dublin
3 2018-04-12 07:48:20 Europe/Prague
4 2018-04-12 11:25:04 Europe/Prague
5 2018-04-12 11:24:38 Europe/Prague
```

**I would like to obtain a vector of times in the local timezone**. I am successful in doing it for a single row:

```
> format(df$UTCTime[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = df$TimeZone[1])
[1] "2018-04-12 19:23:14"
```

However, when I try to apply this to the entire `data.frame` I am getting an error:

```
> apply(df, 1, function(x) format(x["UTCTime"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = x["TimeZone"]))

 Error in format.default(x["UTCTime"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = x["TimeZone"]) : 
  invalid 'trim' argument
```

When I try to pass any other function to `apply`, everything works as expected:

```
> apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(x["UTCTime"], x["TimeZone"]))
[1] "2018-04-12 17:23:14 Europe/Prague" "2018-04-12 17:17:14 Europe/Dublin" "2018-04-12 07:48:20 Europe/Prague"
[4] "2018-04-12 11:25:04 Europe/Prague" "2018-04-12 11:24:38 Europe/Prague"
```

- Why am I getting the `invalid 'trim' argument` here?
- How could I obtain a vector of local times?

Comment: You can't use `apply` here because it coerces a data.frame to a matrix and a matrix can hold (i) only one data type and (ii) cannot hold a POSIXct variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only issue is allowing the timezone to vary. Solution:

```
mapply(df$UTCTime, tz = df$TimeZone, FUN = format)
## [1] "2018-04-12 19:23:14" "2018-04-12 18:17:14" "2018-04-12 09:48:20"
## [4] "2018-04-12 13:25:04" "2018-04-12 13:24:38"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyverse`:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  transmute(LocalTime = format(UTCTime, tz = TimeZone))


# A tibble: 5 x 1
  LocalTime          
  <chr>              
1 2018-04-12 19:23:14
2 2018-04-12 18:17:14
3 2018-04-12 09:48:20
4 2018-04-12 13:25:04
5 2018-04-12 06:24:38
```